# How to handle a variable amount of buttons clicked?

Tags: vb.net

I have a pretty basic problem with button clicks in VB.Net I cannot seem to figure out.

First, I am creating a variable amount of buttons and adding them to the parent form.

```
Private Sub CreateUIObjects()
    For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfButtons
        Dim button As Button = New Button()
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
    Next
End Sub
```

I know it is possible to handle a fixed amount of buttons clicked with the following code

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click '... And so on
        Dim b As Button = CType(sender, Button)

End Sub
```

But what do I do with not 3, but a variable amount of buttons?

Comment: Use AddHandler...but all your buttons will be on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code to experiment with

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CreateUIObjects(3)
End Sub

Dim myButtonNames As String = "foobar"
Private Sub myButtonsClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Debug.WriteLine(b.Name)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateUIObjects(NumberOfButtons As Integer)
    Static ct As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 1 To NumberOfButtons
        ct += 1
        Dim btn As Button = New Button()
        btn.Name = myButtonNames & ct.ToString
        btn.Text = btn.Name
        btn.Location = New Point(ct * 20, ct * 20)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf myButtonsClick
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
```

take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx